# $X$ contains at least two points & at least one isolated point. Prove $X$ is not connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Can we take two sets $G_1 = (x_1)$, where $x_1$ is the isolated point, and $G_2 = B(x_2;\epsilon)-(x_2)$ where $x_2$ is a limit point and show that the set- connectedness conditions hold?

Help would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: The claim seems to be wrong. Consider $X=\{a,b\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset,\{a\},X\}$. Then $a$ is isolated but $X$ is connected.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I gather from the context of this question that $X$ is a metric space, not a general topological space.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Oh, yeah, I just saw it in the "fine-print" (the tags). The OP may wish to incorporate that assumption into the question body ...

Answer (score 1):

You're along the right lines. Use the fact that $x_1$ is isolated to prove that both $\{x_1\}$ and $X-\{x_1\}$ are nonempty open sets. The fact that $x_1$ is isolated gives you that they're open, and the fact that $X$ has at least two points gives you that $X-\{x_1\}$ is nonempty.